# Wordpress Plugin does not appear in Admin Screen

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I created a wordpress plugin. It is not reflecting in the admin module.

Code and screen shots given below.

[Code in structure in Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGRhL.jpg)

[image: Admin Screen]

```
<?php

/**
 * EndpointHelper File Doc Comment.
 *
 * PHP version 7.4.1
 *
 * @category EndpointHelper
 * @package  Helper
 * @author   Bonson Mampilli <bonson.mampilli@company.com>
 * @license  GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE
 * @link     http://test site.com
 * @return   empty string
 */
add_action('admin_init', 'do_something');
/**
 * EndpointHelper File Doc Comment.
 *
 * PHP version 7.4.1
 *
 * @category EndpointHelper
 * @package  Helper
 * @author   Bonson Mampilli <bonson.mampilli@company.com>
 * @license  GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE
 * @link     http://test site.com
 * @return   empty string
 */
function Do_something() 
{
     wp_die('Hello World');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I had to add the following lines in the beginning and it starting
> showing up as a control in the admin screens:
>
> Few additional changes:
>
> 1. ?> was missing at the end
> 2. Added certain items at the beginning. I understand now that they are mandatory for the plugin to be visible.

```
<?php
/**
 * PHP version 7.4.1
 * Plugin Name: My New Plugin
 * Plugin URI: http://yourdomain.com/
 * Description: My new wordpress plugin
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Bonson Mampilli
 * Author URI: http://yourdomain.com
 * License: GPL
 *
 * @category EndpointHelper
 * @package  Helper
 * @author   Bonson Mampilli <bonson.mampilli@company.com>
 * @license  GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE
 * @link     http://test site.com
 * @return   empty string
 */
add_action('admin_init', 'Do_something');
/**
 * PHP version 7.4.1
 * Plugin Name: My New Plugin
 * Plugin URI: http://yourdomain.com/
 * Description: My new wordpress plugin
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Bonson Mampilli
 * Author URI: http://yourdomain.com
 * License: GPL
 *
 * @category EndpointHelper
 * @package  Helper
 * @author   Bonson Mampilli <bonson.mampilli@company.com>
 * @license  GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE
 * @link     http://test site.com
 * @return   empty string
 */
function Do_something() 
{
     wp_die('Hello World');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is from wordpress docs

> `do_action( 'admin_init' )`
> Note, this does not just run on user-facing admin screens. It runs on admin-ajax.php and admin-post.php as well.
> This is roughly analogous to the more general ‘init’ hook, which fires earlier.

Here an example of what you can use to show something in the admin side (for debuging purposes)

```
add_filter('admin_footer_text', 'left_admin_footer_text_output'); //left side
function left_admin_footer_text_output($text) {
  $text = 'How much wood would a woodchuck chuck?';
  return $text;
}
```

Unlike front end, most of the code here is loaded by the admin template via ajax, `die()` and `wp_die()` can work since it mean a fatal error happend,  `echo` will work but you will not see it. check your console and the docs of how to use JS and PHP to load things into the Admin screen, you can start from here.

[image]